# Count the number of elements returned by <call-template>

Tags: xslt, count

I have the following xsl stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="elements">
      <xsl:call-template name="get-some-nodes"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <root>
      <values>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$elements"/>
      </values>
      <count>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($elements)"/>
      </count>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="get-some-nodes">
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>3</node>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(It shouldn't matter what xml you apply it to, it generates its own data).

The result of this of this (using xsltproc) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets">
  <values>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>3</node>
  </values>
  <count>1</count>
</root>
```

Given that the called template returns three nodes, I expected "count($elements)" to be 3, but it is one. I suspected maybe the results were being wrapped up in some sort of root node, but any attempt to do count($elements/*) or similar failed, I believe because $elements is a result tree fragment, and not a node-set.

I don't have access to any of the goodies of exslt or xslt2.0, surely there's a way to get the count of the nodes stored in a variable?

I'd also be happy to count the nodes returned by the call-template without using an intermediate variable, but I can't see how that would be possible.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation and solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="elements"> 
>   <xsl:call-template name="get-some-nodes"/> 
> </xsl:variable> 
>
> <root> 
>   <values> 
>     <xsl:copy-of select="$elements"/> 
>   </values> 
>   <count> 
>     <xsl:value-of select="count($elements)"/> 
>   </count> 
> </root>
> ```

**In XSLT 1.0, whenever nodes are copied into the body of an `<xsl:variable>`, the contents of this variable is an RTF (Result-Tree_fragment)** and needs to be converted to a regular tree before further processing with XPath.

An RTF can be converted to a regular tree only using an extension function, ususally named `xxx:node-set()`, where the `xxx` prefix is bound to a vendor-specific namespace.

To get the number of elements that are at the top level of this tree, you need:

```
count(xxx:node-set($elements)/*)
```

**Here are some namespaces, to which `xxx:` is often bound**:

```
"http://exslt.org/common/"

"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

**In XSLT 2.0 the RTF "type" no longer exists and you can just have**:

```
count($elements/*)
```

if the type of `$elements` isn't specified (the default is `document-node()`)

or

```
count($elements)
```

if the type of `$elements` is specified as `element()*`

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think I have a node-set function available to me. I'm ultimately planning on deploying this as a confluence (atlassian's wiki product) page, and after experimentation it seems to support neither of these extensions. I'm looking for a vanilla XSLT 1 solution, sadly.

Comment: @gfxmonk: It is very likely that your XSLT processor *has* an `xxx:node-set()` function -- most XSLT processors have. What is the XSLT processor you are using? If you don't know, get the result from this function: `system-property(xsl:vendor)` or `system-property(xsl:vendor-url)`.

Comment: Ahh that's a good trick to know. I'm using apache xalan-j. However, I am intending to run this with multiple xslt processors (xalan and libxslt), so I would still vastly prefer a solution without using such extensions.

Comment: Also, after trying to use the xalan nodeset function, it doesn't actually work (and gives me no output or errors). I guess it's possible confluence runs this in some sort of restricted environment?

Comment: @gfxmonk: For Xalan, the namespace is: `http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` So, add to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` this namespace: `xmlns:vendor="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and then try `vendor:nodeset()` . Note that there is no hyphen in the name of this extension function.

Comment: @gfxmonk: libxslt must support EXSLT. `exsl:node-set()` should work, where `exsl:` is bound to "http://exslt.org/common" . Try it. I am sure Xalan also supports EXSLT.

Comment: I've tried it, and no luck (I've raised a bug with confluence to get it supported, but who knows if that'll ever happen). But the point remains that a solution that works in one or the other is not really ideal. Is there no other approach?

Comment: @gfxmonk: Here is an example from Xalan documentation: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#ex-nodeset

Comment: @gfxmonk: I wrote the first version of FXSL 7-8 years ago. Even at that time Xalan had its `xxx:nodeset()` function. You can dounload FXSL for Xalan her: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/fxsl/FXSL%201.1/fxsl-Xalan-1.1.zip/download and you will see examples how to use the `xxx:nodeset()` function

Comment: @gfxmonk: You can set the result of the `exslt:node-set()` or `xxx:nodeset()` in the body of a single variable. This is a known and used technique. In the body of the variable you have an `<xsl:choose>` and in its two branches you test for `function-available(exsl:node-set)` and for `function-available(xxx:nodeset)` . If the result is true, you apply the function to your RTF and the returned tree is the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get that working now. I still can't extract the function-available() checks into a template to call, but maybe that's not even possible. It's an ugly solution, but it may be the only possible one. Thanks for all your help, Dimitre!